# powershell : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: powershell

i am not a programmer but i am trying to run this powershell script to get multiple website screenshots with internet exporer ( not my script )

can anyone help to find out what is wrong with it because i am stack and i dont know what to do.

thnx in advance

```
# Author: Shawn Keene
# Date: 09/12/2019
# Powershell script to automate Internet Explorer and grab screenshots

$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
cd $ScriptPath

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

function screenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, $path) {
$bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
$graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

$graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

$bmp.Save($path)

$graphics.Dispose()
$bmp.Dispose()
}

$bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(4, 110, 1580, 1584)      #area for screenshot

cls
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Starting... Move or minimize this window."
sleep 3                                                          #give the user 3 seconds to minimize 
or move the powershell window out of the way

$iterator = 1;
$OutputFile = "screenshot-log.log"                               #just in case we need to debug 
something later

$products = import-csv "urls.csv" | foreach {                    #load a 2-column CSV with headers of 
"filename" (for picture file) and "url" to visit

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;          #initialize a fresh browser window for 
each row of the CSV
$ie.top = 0;
$ie.left = -8;                                               #because windows 10 has an invisible 
grab borders unless you use AeroLite theme
$ie.height = 1600;
$ie.width = 1600;
$ie.visible = $true;

$ie.navigate("about:blank");
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1};

$startTime = Get-Date                                       #start the stopwatch and log it
write-host $iterator.ToString() `t $_.url

$ie.navigate($_.url);                                       #go to the website and wait for browser 
to become idle

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1};
sleep 3                                                     #wait at least 3 seconds and then check 
for idle one more time to be sure
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1};

$endTime = get-date                                         #end timer

$filepath = "Results\" + $_.filename + ".png"               #place screenshots into the Results 
subfolder of the current working directory

screenshot $bounds $scriptpath\$filepath                    #say cheese

#log the result to the log file
$iterator.ToString() + "`t" + $_.filename + "`t" + $_.url + "`t" + $startTime.DateTime + "`t" + 
($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds" >> $outputFile

$ie.quit();                                                 #close the browser process

$iterator = $iterator+1;
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "All Done!";
```

**and i am get this error**

```
Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."
At line:7 char:4
+    $bmp.Save($path)
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

can anyone help to find out what is wrong with it because i am stack and i dont know what to do.

thnx in advance

Comment: How does your `urls.csv` look like?

Comment: thnx you, you help me to figurate out the problem. the problem was the file name, i give name with ":" on it and windows dont allow that. thnx again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

- The following answer **applies to *Windows***.
- Unix-like platforms (supported by PowerShell [Core] v6+) have different rules; notably, there are no drive letters<sup>[1]</sup>, and `:` is therefore a legal character in a file name; except for `/` , which is invariably the *path separator*, there are virtually no restrictions on what characters you may use in a file name, including `\`.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

As you've since confirmed, the problem was that **a `filename` column value in your input CSV file contained a `:` (colon) character**, but **a mere file *name* isn't allowed to contain `:`**

**`:` is only allowed in a file *path*, *once*, as part of a *drive specification*** (e.g., `C:`)

A `:` in any other part of a path triggers the exception you saw, which surfaces as a *statement-terminating* error in PowerShell (error message abbreviated below); e.g.:

```
# On Windows
PS> [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("C:\foo:bar")
"The given path's format is not supported."
```

---

A **related error** shows if you try to use **characters that are *fundamentally* unsupported in file names**, notably one of: `: * ? " < > |`  (`\ /` too cannot be used in file *names*, only as separators in *paths*); note that the error message changed in PowerShell [Core] v6+:

```
# Windows PowerShell
PS> [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("foo?bar")
"Illegal characters in path."

# PowerShell [Core] v6+ on Windows
PS> [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("foo?bar")
"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."
```

---

The **above errors are both due to *invalid file-system path syntax***.

By contrast, **if the path is syntactically valid but *the target directory doesn't exist***, you'll see *yet another error*:

```
# On Windows.
PS> [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("NoSuchSubdir\file.txt")
"Could not find a part of the path '...'."
```

With `/` as the separator, you'd see the same error on Unix-like platforms.

---

<sup>[1] Paths based on *PowerShell-only* drive definitions (created with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)) can have drive specifications on Unix too, but you cannot pass such paths to *.NET methods* (such as in this case), because .NET doesn't understand them.</sup>

<sup>[2] This applies to .NET method calls and calls to native utilities; PowerShell, in an attempt to unify behavior across platforms, allows use of `\` as the path separator on Unix as well, which can be problematic - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9244).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You have to meet the following two prerequisites in order to make this script work:

1. You need a CSV file named `urls.csv` at the location where your script is stored. This file has to contain two comma-delimited columns with headers `filename`and `url`. Also note, that the filename has to be provided without an extension. Example:

```
filename,url
test,https://www.google.com
```

2. You need a folder named "Results" at the destination where this script is stored. You will find your screenshots inside this folder then.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create Results directory first to save the screenshots, I tested and creating the directory solved the problem

Correction: Issue is in the filename inputs supplied from csv, which contain the characters like ':' which are not supported for filename in windows

Detailed answer given below by @mklement0

Comment: the problem was the file name i but ":" on the name and not allowed from the windows. Thnx for your efford

Answer (score 0):

If you get path error in powershell, use below script: Basically divide your path into 3 parts.

```
$sSecStrPassword = "Come up with something secure!";
$FilePath = "c:\a\";
$FileName = "mycert";
$FileType = ".pfx";
$certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$certificateObject.Import($FilePath+$FileName+$FileType, $sSecStrPassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet);
return $certificateObject.Thumbprint;
```